# Forcing Oracle drivers to output TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE to java.sql.Timestamp when using getObject

Tags: java, sql, oracle, timestamp

I've been working on some code that we are planning on making work across both Postgres and Oracle.

One issue is we've been using TIMESTAMP columns with Oracle, but would like to migrate to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE columns. The reason for this change is we'd like to take advantage of the more portable CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead of SYSTIMESTAMP.

In order for this change to make sense, we'd like to use TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE as it could be possible a client is in a separate time zone, in which case I'm worried the more portable CURRENT_TIMESTAMP into a TIMESTAMP (without timezone) column would reflect a different date if a client is in a different time zone than a SYSTIMESTAMP into a TIMESTAMP column.

In Oracle, this is verified in the following example, which produces a 2 hours offset when the server is in the -7 from UTC:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '-5:0';
select SYSTIMESTAMP from dual;
select CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP) from dual;
```

So, that's the rationale for using TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.

Now, for an example of the madness that is getObject:

```
CREATE TABLE FILE_STORE (
    NAME VARCHAR2(256), 
    CREATE_DATE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);
INSERT INTO FILE_STORE (NAME, CREATE_DATE) VALUES('MyFile',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

With the java example:

```
String sql = "SELECT CREATE_DATE FROM FILE_STORE WHERE NAME = ?";

try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)){
    stmt.setString(1,"MyFile");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    java.sql.Timestamp time = rs.getTimestamp("CREATE_DATE");
    System.out.println(time.toLocaleString());
}

try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)){
    stmt.setString(1,"MyFile");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ time = (oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ) rs.getObject( "CREATE_DATE");
    System.out.println(time.timestampValue( conn ).toLocaleString());
}
```

With output:

```
Apr 15, 2014 11:15:04 AM (Correct absolute time)
Apr 15, 2014 11:15:04 AM (Correct absolute time)
```

So, the madness here is this:

Using getObject returns the relatively useless oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ, which requires a connection and a method call to return a java.sql.Timestamp with unix epoch.

What would be nice is if I could force getObject just behaved the exact same way as getTimestamp through some flag.

Comment: i had used `java.util.Date` to get the Date object. It returns the date-time with timezone. I had stored it in db as a varchar2. You can retrieve as a date and parse it back to a date.